# Convert a string with list syntax into list(s)

Tags: python, string, list, csv

I am trying to convert a string into lists.  The structure of the string (of which I have a database full of them) is always that of n lists within a list.  However, I have them in string format. These data come from a column in a large .csv file that I have.

```
stringOfLists1 = [["Social","Food and Dining","Restaurants","American"]["Social","Food and Dining","Restaurants","Pizza"]]
stringOfLists2 = [["Social","Food and Dining","Restaurants"]]
stringOfLists3 = [[...]]
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to parse each of these lists.

```
listOfLists1
>>> [["Social","Food and Dining","Restaurants","American"]["Social","Food and Dining","Restaurants","Pizza"]]
listOfLists1[0]
>>> ["Social","Food and Dining","Restaurants","American"]
type(listOfLists1)
>>> 'list'
type(listOfLists1[0])
>>> 'list'
type(listOfLists1[0][3])
>>> 'string'
listOfLists1[0][3]
>>> 'American'
```

I hope I have explained the problem thoroughly!  Ultimately, I am trying to understand and quickly parse all of the elements of the list in the database, but that is beyond the scope of this question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> stringOfLists1 = '[["Social","Food and Dining","Restaurants","American"], ["Social","Food and Dining","Restaurants","Pizza"]]'
>>> lst = literal_eval(stringOfLists1)
>>> lst
[['Social', 'Food and Dining', 'Restaurants', 'American'], ['Social', 'Food and Dining', 'Restaurants', 'Pizza']]
>>> type(lst)
<class 'list'>
>>> type(lst[0])
<class 'list'>
>>> type(lst[0][3])
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

It will parse each string into a list of lists of strings without the security risks of `eval`.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That's really elegant and simple.